Error with terraform plan (DetailedError{Original:adal.tokenRefreshError)
I'm having issue deploying this on terraform. Im very new to this but i manage to get all the way here lol. My terraform init no issue. But i couldnt get pass the error below. I have encoded the environment variable as follow. Understood that my terraform version is old but the document the application im referring to recomends use of this one. Im seeing error in ADAL and its already replaced by MSAL but is there a way to bypass this? Any recommendation? thanks!
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="xxxxxx"
export ARM_TENANT_ID="xxxxxx"
export ARM_CLIENT_ID="xxxxxx",
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="xxxxxxx",

$ terraform version
Terraform v0.11.11
+ provider.azurerm v1.44.0
+ provider.local v1.4.0
+ provider.null v2.1.2
+ provider.template v2.2.0
+ provider.tls v2.2.0

{
  "azure-cli": "2.59.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.59.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.1.0",
  "extensions": {
    "ml": "2.24.0"
  }
}


 provider.azurerm: Error building account: Error getting authenticated object ID: Error listing Service Principals: autorest.DetailedError{Original:adal.tokenRefreshError{message:"adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '400'. Response body: {\"error\":\"unauthorized_client\",\"error_description\":\"AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx,' was not found in the directory 'Contoso'. "error_codes\":[700016],\"timestamp\":\"2024-04-24 05:36:25Z\",\"trace_id\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx\",\"correlation_id\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"error_uri\":\"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700016\"}", resp:(*http.Response)(0xc000a8e090)}, PackageType:"azure.BearerAuthorizer", Method:"WithAuthorization", StatusCode:400, Message:"Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://graph.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/servicePrincipals?%24filter=appId+eq+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxpi-version=1.6", ServiceError:[]uint8(nil), Response:(*http.Response)(0xc000a8e090)}

Able to run terraform plan with no error.

I'd probably start with a newer terraform version. 0.11.11 is around five years old. :)


Im seeing error in ADAL and its already replaced by MSAL but is there a way to bypass this? Any recommendation? thanks!

Thanks to Mark for suggesting to use the latest version of Terraform.
To resolve the issue, you may need to install the latest version of Terraform, which is Version 1.8.2, from here.
Powershell
> $env:ARM_CLIENT_ID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
> $env:ARM_CLIENT_SECRET = "12345678-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
> $env:ARM_TENANT_ID = "10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
> $env:ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"


Make sure to use the latest version of the azurerm provider.
 
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
          source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
          version = "=3.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }


Reference: Azure Provider: Authenticating using a Service Principal with a Client Secret
Terraform version list

I resolve this by removing the , on the environment variable. thanks all!
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="xxxxxx"
export ARM_TENANT_ID="xxxxxx"
export ARM_CLIENT_ID="xxxxxx",
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="xxxxxxx",

to
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="xxxxxx"
export ARM_TENANT_ID="xxxxxx"
export ARM_CLIENT_ID="xxxxxx"
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="xxxxxxx"

